# Can't find UnityEngine.UI namespace after installing Visual StudioTools for Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-2015

I have been using Visual Studio 2015 community (version 14.0.25123.00 Update 2) with .Net framework v4.6.01038 with Unity Tools for VS2015 which I used to debug my unity projects. Everything seemed to work fine but after I tried to work with UnityEngine.UI VS start showing errors saying that the namespace can't be found. I have used the exact same project files in to another pc where the only difference was in .Net framework version (v4.6.01055)and that worked. If I remove the unity tools from my previous pc, the build error goes away but I guess there is no way to debug without the unity tools. Is this a issue with .net framework or I am missing something? 
 - I tried to export and re-import all unity assets and packages but that did not solve the issue
 - VS2015 was uninstalled and reinstalled from scratch - still did not work
 - unity tools was also reinstalled
 - Also deleted the projectFolder\Library\UnityAssemblies folder and restarted VS2005.

None of these methods seems to work for me. Tried to find the exact version of  .net framework but failed too. Is there a specific solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I finally found a workaround of this issue and I pretty much think that the .Net framework version was not occurring any problem here. The solution is to Setting the Api Compatibility Level from ".NET 2.0 Subset" to ".NET 2.0". To do this in unity perform the following steps:

**Unity > Edit > Project Settings > Player > Api Compatibility Level**

From: ".NET 2.0 Subset"
To ".NET 2.0"

Do perform a restart to both Unity and VS2015 (if the above solution doesn't work right then)

Comment: You don't have to change the Api Compatibility Level to fix it. Simply following direction should have worked.

Comment: I did them at least thrice. Installing VS2015 from unity didn't solve the issue for me. I still saw the .Net version of 4.6 even after removing VS. Right now by changing the API level, VS2015 is working as expected the .Net version is still the same !

Answer (score 0):

Go to: Edit > Preference > External Tools. in External script editor > click on browse > go to unity file > Editor File and click on mono develop.